# Seperate/Different Texture for One level for whole environment than other level

Tags: graphics, textures, unity-game-engine, mesh

i'm completely new to unity so need you people's help. I have a environment which has grassy texture for first level,which is perfect,Now i want to give Snow Area look & feel to my whole Environment using snow texture for second level and in third level,a desert look to my environment by using desert texture on environment.

difficulty i'm facing is the environment has hundred of gameobjects with Mesh Renderers. it is almost impossible for me to access the hundred of meshrenderer and assign texture using script.

Can anybody give the simple and best solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Often times it's common to have different prefabs with different materials for the scene you're building. But if the only difference is the texture, there is a pretty easy solution:

MeshRenderers share materials, which means a change to the material's texture should cause all of the MeshRenderers using that material to update.

The easiest way to change this texture (outside of the editor) would be to have a script on each scene that changes the Material to have the texture you want. Something like this:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TextureSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material materialToChange;
    public Texture targetTexture;

    private void Awake()
    {
        materialToChange.SetTexture("_MainTex", targetTexture);
    }
}
```

When you run your game, you should see all of the objects with the material you set update:

Go from this:
[image]

To this when you run the game:
[image]

Comment: it is really very helpful
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You so much @Thomas Bartlett to answer.
Your Answer showed me way to solve my issue.
in your case it would be a bit lengthy,i guess,to go to each gameobject having meshrenderer and access the material and change texture.
Their is an easy way,i find.

Make Use of Plugin "Simple Mesh Combiner",it will combine all the Materials being used on all the meshrenderers in the environment on single Empty game Object,as shown in attached image.

After getting all the materials on single gameobject,attach the script on that single gameobject and access the materials as shown in @Thomas Bartlett script and Enjoy. :)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKHUK.png)

Link to Get Plugin Mesh combiner is given below

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9qb7f3q60zdrn8c/AAAWD7fEvdmMxpvYrFYXH3a5a?dl=0)

their could be one more way is to make the atlas for one type of textures(Lets say grassy look and feel environment) and another atlas for snow look and feel Environment and just replace the atlas as according to levels or requirments.(but i havent applied this solution,i hope it will work too)

Thanks :)